# How can I move all files matching a pattern into a new folder?

Tags: command-line, directory-structure

I have files like these :

```
- REPORT_100_COMPLETED.csv
- REPORT_100_FAILED.csv
- REPORT_101_COMPLETED.csv
- REPORT_101_FAILED.csv
- REPORT_102_COMPLETED.csv
- REPORT_102_FAILED.csv
```

I want all of them to be put inside subfolder according to the related id :

```
100
  | REPORT_100_COMPLETED.csv
  | REPORT_100_FAILED.csv
101
  | REPORT_101_COMPLETED.csv
  | REPORT_101_FAILED.csv
102
  | REPORT_102_COMPLETED.csv
  | REPORT_102_FAILED.csv
```

and so on, anyone can help? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bsh
for i in REPORT_*_*.csv ;do
  dir=$(cut -d'_' -f2 <<<$i)
  mkdir -p $dir && mv $i $dir/
done
```